# How to design a Turing Enumerator which either ends with 011 or is of odd length?

Tags: turing-machines

This question was asked by my professor in optional brain teaser section, I have tried to solve it for last 48 hours, I am not able to construct a deterministic Turing Machine, Can someone provide hint or something because this seems like impossible to me :( ..

Comment: Cross-posted on cstheory: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30526/how-to-design-a-turing-enumerator-which-either-ends-with-011-or-is-of-odd-length - please don't cross-post.

Comment: please explain better what you mean

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "a Turing enumerator which either ends with 011 or is of odd length". The phrase "Turing enumerator" is not standard in computer science, so you need to define what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're looking for a Turing machine that *decides* the language $L$ consisting of all words ending with 011 or of odd length.

Hint: You're lucky since $L$ is regular. Construct a DFA for $L$ and rephrase it as a Turing machine.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But as soon as I posted this question, I was scribbling and found the answer, I was thinking same that it can be done with the help of DFA, but I playing around and most probably got the answer. Thank you :)